# Is there a hive condition to exit out if the table count is zero or equals a number?

Tags: shell, hive, hiveql

I am using shell to trigger hive and run the queries in hql file where there are more than 10 queries.

My question : Is there a way were we can exit out of hive and return back to shell if my first query returns zero.

For better understanding : 
IF  select COUNT(*) from mytable is 0 then exit ELSE continue ;

Answer (score 1):

You can move this logic to the shell:

```
 rowcount=$(hive -S -e "select COUNT(*) from mytable")
 if [ $rowcount == 0 ] ;then 
    exit
  else echo ok; #run your script here 
 fi;
```

Also in Hive you can use assert_true() function to check boolean expression. If False, the script will fail with exception: ASSERT_TRUE(): assertion failed:

```
 select assert_true(COUNT(*)!=0) from mytable
```

Comment: Yes Currently I am doing the same but there are some performance issues to invoke hive after each check . But thank you fro your reply.

Comment: @settle proposed solution using assert_true()